# Entity Framework Pagination Performance Considerations

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, pagination

I'm fairly unfamiliar with complex queries in Entity Framework 6, so I had a question associated to pagination.

The scenario is as follows: I have a project that I have described the data model in my own form and using T4 templates, it generates the appropriate Entity, High Fidelity Change Tracking companion entity, a complex dynamic search query entity which is used to ask questions about the associated model (eg. entity.SearchNameCriterium = "t"; entity.SearchNameType = StringSearchType.StartsWith, with a UI built around this it would enable a user a powerful search tool.)

Into this, I have a part where pagination is used to drop down a list of constituent elements:
[image: WPF Styled Application]
When I insert something using the Insert Button, if this overflows into the next page (at 'x' number of items each time, defined in a constant -- I will later move this to a setting)  I use the following code:

```
this.context.SaveChanges();
int offset = searchCurItemLstCriteriaSkip - 1;
var queryBase = this.queryCurItemLstFormContainer;
int idFind = newDataContext.Identifier;
while (queryBase.Any())
{
    queryBase = queryCurItemLstFormContainer.Skip((++offset) * searchCriteriaCount).Take(searchCriteriaCount);
    if (queryBase.Any(k => k.Identifier == idFind))
    {
        this.searchCurItemLstCriteriaSkip = offset * searchCriteriaCount;
        break;
    }
}
```

The rationale is the item will always be entered at a point within the DB on the current page or after the current page, so you can in theory start at the current page and move forward.

I just want to know if there's a better way to do this, or if this methodology works...?  In case anyone wonders: the combobox is used to select current item because a list would just waste space, you only ever need one item at a time, and search functionality works just as well in the ComboBox's dropdown.  The UI elements associated to this are generated XAML through the text templates.

I just want to be sure I understand the kind of impact the query on moving to the newest page could have on very large databases.

What are the performance considerations of doing a query.Select(k=>k.Identifier).Count() / itemsPerPage?  Would that be quicker in this instance?

Insight more than welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the focus of this, using Count() on the query, and limiting the selection to the identifier: it is a few orders of magnitude faster to use the Count functionality.

Rationale behind this is: if you're paging and you use the iterative approach, if there are 10,000 records, and 25 items per page, that's at least 800 queries (400 for checking if there's more items, 400 for checking the identifier range) that hit the database, whereas the Count is only one.

Even though the Count can be seen as a potentially costly operation, the latency between all of the queries to the database in the originally stated method is greater than a single Count request.  Sometimes the simplest solution is the best.